# getting error like 'Android resource linking failed'

Tags: android

In this error  some classes are not found[image: I got this error everywhere]

```
Output:  warn: removing resource com.kss.krishnasalesandservice:string/abc_action_bar_home_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.kss.krishnasalesandservice:string/abc_action_bar_up_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.kss.krishnasalesandservice:string/abc_action_menu_overflow_description without required default value.
```

Comment: Could you check your `strings.xml` has no empty entry ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `R` in your Activity File..look at in your Activity file there might have been `R` showing in RED color..place your mouse over it and press Alt+Enter..it will import `R` Class.

Answer (score 0):

android:name="check your activity name"

add this in your style.xml

```
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>
```

and this in your manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```